# BigQuery Google Sheets How to Query Dynamic Table Names

Tags: google-bigquery

I have tables of stocks in my BigQuery. The names of the table is simply the ticker of the stocks: AAPL, AMZN, MSFT, etc.

```
"{dataset_name}.AAPL"
"{dataset_name}.AMZN"
"{dataset_name}.MSFT"
```

I am on Google Sheets that's trying to create a query to dynamically SELECT from the tables one by one, based on the stock names.

So I'm trying to use a parameter on the table name, and I tried to use the [wildcard function from Bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference).

```
SELECT * FROM `dataset_name.*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'AAPL'
```

The result is `Query valid. Will process 0 bytes.` and returns nothing.

I then tried modifying the query and make it like this

```
SELECT * FROM `dataset_name.A*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'APL'
```

And it works...

The problem is, I cannot wildcard the whole table name. I can only use it for a suffix name, with at least a letter at the front of the name. However in my case, the whole table name is dynamic. How to make a query for a dynamic whole table name?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As per my understanding, `dataset_name.*` should work.  check this one. 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#querying_all_tables_in_a_dataset

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior in BigQuery, as per this [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#query_execution_details):

> In order to execute a standard SQL query that uses a wildcard table, BigQuery automatically infers the schema for that table. BigQuery uses the schema for the most recently created table that matches the wildcard as the schema for the wildcard table.

It is possible in your scenario that you have tables in your dataset that has  different schema, and BigQuery references to the most recently created table.

One way to dynamically SELECT without using `_TABLE_SUFFIX` in Bigquery is to use [`execute_immediate`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate) and put the suffix into a variable. However, this seems to be a limitation in Google Sheets. To request to have this feature in Google Sheets, you may file a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: I see. I ended up using App Script to loop for all dynamic parameters. But thanks anyways.

Comment: Glad that this answer shed some useful information. You can check this SO post: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)